# Image plane is not visible through glass

Tags: animation, transparency, glass, render-passes, shrinkwrap

I have an image-sequence as a plane imported to Blender in cycles.
I used a "Shrinkwrap" modifier to wrap it on the Body.
[image]
When I now put the glass helmet on the character the image plane is not visible anymore.
[image]
What is happening here?

Thanks for your help

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: Okay, should I put textures in an folder with the blend file?

Comment: if they are not necessary to reproduce the problem - no else yes.

Comment: I removed everything where I thought it would not be necessary. The face textures are in the folder:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/18nQwnTkwY-_UTwiwMg_oE_jTN8bT0Z54?usp=sharing

Comment: Does the file work?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you have set your Face object to be invisible to all rays except for camera rays.  Camera rays are rays that project out from the screen.  Once these camera rays hit any rendering object, they cease to be camera rays.  For example, once they hit the surface of Helmet, and refract, they turn into transmission rays.  For your face to be seen by these refracted rays, you need to enable Transmission in properties/object/ray visibility.

However, that takes care only of renders in Cycles (the rendering engine you have designated in the file.)  If you plan to render in Eevee, there is an additional problem.  And material previews, like that in your second picture, use Eevee.

To fix the Eevee/material view, you need to first change your rendering engine to Eevee in properties/render, then select your Face object.  In properties/material/settings, you'll see that the material is set to "Alpha Blend".  Alpha Blend is nice when it works, but it's unreliable (it relies on Blender getting an accurate draw order for transparent surfaces.)  In this case, you should change this to Alpha Clip, which is appropriate for the hard-edged image you're using.  In other cases, you might need to use Alpha Hashed for this.

After changing this, you can change your rendering engine back to Cycles if you want; the changed material settings will still be used by your material preview.

[image]